# Relative Boardman-Vogt construction on topological spaces

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $f:P\to  Q$ be an operad map in $TOP$ (compactly generated topological spaces category). Please, I would like to know the explict relations over trees involving the relative Boardman-Vogt construction $W(f:P\to Q)$ in $TOP$. I know that it must consider metric trees with labelled vertices by $P$ and $Q$ (mixed I guess), I'd like to know the identifications.

Comment: Do you have a definition for this in general? I thought that Berger--Moerdijk only define this for $f$ a $\Sigma$-cofibration between well-pointed $\Sigma$-cofibrant operads (Thm. 7.1).

Comment: I guess these hypothesis just ensure we get a "good" factorization P->P[u}->W(f)->W(Q), just like the full W-construction, the construction works for any topological operad, but it do not give a cofibrant replacement in general for it.